# is there a work around ReferenceError: process is not defined at node_modules/pg/lib/defaults.js

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, reference, vite

## Background

I am using Vite, React, Node, and PostgreSQL for my website, and upon trying to use something from 'pg' in a React file I get this error:

```
caught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at node_modules/pg/lib/defaults.js (defaults.js:8:9)
    at __require (chunk-DFKQJ226.js?v=b31be839:8:50)
    at node_modules/pg/lib/utils.js (utils.js:5:18)
    at __require (chunk-DFKQJ226.js?v=b31be839:8:50)
    at node_modules/pg/lib/client.js (client.js:4:13)
    at __require (chunk-DFKQJ226.js?v=b31be839:8:50)
    at node_modules/pg/lib/index.js (index.js:3:14)
    at __require (chunk-DFKQJ226.js?v=b31be839:8:50)
    at index.js:55:1
```

here is my server.js file:

```js
import pg from 'pg'

const { Client } = pg

const client = new Client({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '5432',
    user: 'postgres',
    password: 'pass',
    database: 'name'
})

//code

export default client;
```

here is my Login.jsx file:

`import client from '../server.js';`

These files are relative because the error does not appear in the terminal if I ran
`node server.js`
but on
`npm run dev`

## Testing

Upon some research I managed to deduce that Vite changed the naming of process to something else which is why it is not defined.

I tried installing a webpack which I seemed to have done wrong.

I tried changing the vite.config.js file to declare process as empty since I saw it online. I would get another error.

How can I manage a workaround such problem?

Thank you in advance.